# How to minimise the terminal automatically when it is running a shell script?

Tags: macos, terminal, command-line, python

I have a shell script which runs a Python Program. I created the shell script so that the users of my program may simply double click it to run my program.

When the shell script is executed; the terminal loads in front of the GUI of the Python Program and that is bothersome. Is there anyway to ensure that the Terminal is minimised by default when the shell script runs?

Comment: You had two questions in here. This site works better when there is only one question per question. That way, it's easier for other people to find solutions if they have the same problem. I've edited out your second question, but feel free to ask it separately.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So I found out a solution.

Turns you can simply use Automator and save the shell script as an App.

Just open Automator; select "Applications" and then "Run a Shell Script"

Comment: Kudos answering your own question. I was about to suggest the same.

Comment: I asked a friend who happens to be a Mac Expert and he is the one who suggested this.